# upgrading oracle 11 to oracle 18

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to upgrade Oracle11 database to Oracle 18XE without uninstalling Oracle 11 ? I searched from Oracle forums and website but I could not find any Readme file which tells how to upgrade it ?

I will be grateful if you can help me

Cheers

Comment: Don't rely on forums and websites. There's the official documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/upgrd/index.html

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading oracle database will never mandate you to uninstall the source binary. You can just install the target binary(18XE) in any location and upgrade. Make sure you follow the proper steps and have a complete DB backup, if at all something goes wrong. You should run the following script to check the status and readiness of the database:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/
sqlplus '/ as sysdba'
spool dbupgrade_info.log
@dbupgdiag.sql
spool off
```

this gives the current status of the database like the components and invalid objects. Make sure you do not have any invalid components and invalid objects in SYS/SYSTEM Schema.

Install the target binaries, and  then execute pre-upgrade script from source home :

```
$SOURCE_HOME/jdk/bin/java -jar $TARGET_HOME/rdbms/admin/preupgrade.jar FILE TEXT DIR <output_dir>
```

The required scripts will be generated in the .
Now you can shut the DB & Listener down and change the environment variables pointing to the target home, copy the pfile to the target location and then,

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"
startup nomount
shutdown immediate;
```

That was just to make sure that the pfile is working fine.

Now you can start the actual DB upgrade(Make sure this is in target(18XE) environment):

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin
sqlplus '/ as sysdba'
startup upgrade;
exit
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
./dbupgrade
```

Now run the `postupgrade_fixups.sql` that will be in the .

As simple as that. Remember to configure the `tnsnames.ora` and `linstener.ora` in `$TNS_ADMIN` locations. And then startup the listener.